# Problem after converting my HTML site to PHP ( echo ''; echo ''; everywhere)

Tags: php, html, converters

I tried to convert my static html site pages with an online HTML to PHP converter. I changed all my extensions to .php and also the links. You can see the result of the conversion below. I run it with wamp but some stuff (images, css, text) of the page is shown in the browser, but most of the stuff is not, and instead I see

> '; echo ''; echo ''; echo ''; echo ''; echo ''; echo ''; echo '';
>   echo ''; echo ''; echo ''; echo ''; echo ''; echo ''; echo ''; echo
>   ''; echo '

everywhere.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<? php
echo '<!DOCTYPE html>';
echo '<html lang="en">';

echo '<head>';
echo '<meta charset="utf-8">';
echo '<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">';
echo '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">';
echo '<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->';
echo '<title>Title</title>';

echo '<!-- Bootstrap -->';
echo '<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">';
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">';

echo '<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->';
echo '<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->';
echo '<!--[if lt IE 9]>';
echo '<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>';
echo '<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>';
echo '<![endif]-->';
echo '</head>';
echo '<body>';
echo '<nav class="navbar navbar-default">';
echo '<div class="container">';
echo '<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->';
echo '<div class="navbar-header">';
echo '<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">';
echo '<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>';
echo '<span class="icon-bar"></span>';
echo '<span class="icon-bar"></span>';
echo '<span class="icon-bar"></span>';
echo '</button>';
echo '<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" width="150px"></a>';
echo '</div>';

echo '<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->';
echo '<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">';
echo '<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">';
echo '<li class="active"><a href="index.php">HOME <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>';

echo '<li class="dropdown">';
echo '<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">text <span class="caret"></span></a>';
echo '<ul class="dropdown-menu">';

echo '<li><a href="one.php">some link</a></li>';
echo '<li role="separator" class="divider"></li>';
echo '<li><a href="two.php">something</a></li>';
echo '<li role="separator" class="divider"></li>';
echo '<li><a href="three.php">something else</a></li>';
echo '</ul>';
echo '</li>';
echo '<li class="dropdown">';
echo '<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">something<span class="caret"></span></a>';
echo '<ul class="dropdown-menu">';
echo '<li><a href="four.php">something</a></li>';
echo '<li role="separator" class="divider"></li>';
echo '<li><a href="five.php">some link</a></li>';
echo '<li role="separator" class="divider"></li>';
echo '<li></><a href="six.php"> something</a></li>';
echo '<li role="separator" class="divider"></li>';
echo '<li></><a href="seven.php">something</a></li>';
echo '</ul>';
echo '</li>';


echo '<li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">something<span class="caret"></span></a>';
echo '<ul class="dropdown-menu">';
echo '<li><a href="eight.php">something</a></li>';
echo '<li role="separator" class="divider"></li>';
echo '<li><a href="nine.php">something</a></li>';
echo '<li role="separator" class="divider"></li>';
echo '<li></><a href="ten.php">something</a></li>';
echo '<li role="separator" class="divider"></li>';
echo '<li></><a href="elevne.php">something</a></li>';
echo '</ul>';
echo '</li>';


echo '</ul>';
echo '</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->';
echo '</div><!-- /.container-->';
echo '</nav>';
echo '<!-- Carousal -->';


echo '<section class="jk-slider">';
echo '<div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">';
echo '<ol class="carousel-indicators">';
echo '<li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>';
echo '<li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="1"></li>';
echo '<li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="2"></li>';
echo '</ol>';

echo '<div class="carousel-inner">';

echo '<div class="item active">';
echo '<div class="hero">';
echo '<hgroup>';
echo '<p>something</p>';

echo '</hgroup>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="overlay"></div>';
echo '<a href="#"><img src="images/1.jpg" class="img-responsive" width="100%"></a>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="item">';
echo '<div class="hero">';
echo '<hgroup>';
echo '<p>something</p>';

echo '</hgroup>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="overlay"></div>';
echo '<a href="#"><img src="images/2.jpg" class="img-responsive" width="100%"></a>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="item">';
echo '<div class="hero">';
echo '<hgroup>';
echo '<p>something</p>';

echo '</hgroup>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="overlay"></div>';
echo '<a href="#"><img src="images/3.jpg" /></a>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example" data-slide="prev">';
echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>';
echo '</a>';
echo '<a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example" data-slide="next">';
echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>';
echo '</a>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</section>';
echo '<!-- End Of carousal -->';

echo '<section>';
echo '<div class="container">';
echo '<div class="row">';
echo '<div class="col-md-12">';
echo '&nbsp;';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</section>';


echo '<script src="../../ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>';
echo '<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->';
echo '<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>';
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';

echo '$('.count').each(function () {';
echo '$(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({';
echo 'Counter: $(this).text()';
echo '}, {';
echo 'duration: 5000,';
echo 'easing: 'swing',';
echo 'step: function (now) {';
echo '$(this).text(Math.ceil(now));';
echo '}';
echo '});';
echo '});';
echo '</script>';

echo '</script>';
echo '</body>';


echo '</html>';
?>
```

Comment: `<? php` WRONG .... `<?php` CORRECT

Comment: that's just a really bad idea, no reason to echo plain text\html everywhere

Comment: And there is No Need to echo all the HTML. The `<?php` tag turns the interpreter On and `?>` turns it Off. So after a ?> yuo are writing raw HTML

Comment: In fact in this page there is NO PHP therefore it could have been left as simple HTML

Comment: also this too has added php syntax errors,by not escaping single quotes.

Comment: If you want to convert to `echo`s then make sure to escape your quotes. `doesn't` is causing issue #1 and I will let you find the rest.

Comment: thank you a lot guys for your immediate response. This is what the online converter exported. I know it should be a plain html but I need to have them with a .php format So I have to do <?php instead of <? php and just includethe raw HTML between <?php and ?> to make it work in a php format?

Comment: instead of doesn't can i use doesn/'t to prevent it from escaping?

Comment: " but I need to have them with a .php format " really that makes no sense, you can just put raw html in a *.php file

Comment: so I just can change my .html extensions to .php and change the links from .html to .php?

Comment: then if the converting from php to html works only for php functionalities, why those converters exist?

Comment: If you already have a valid HTML file, just changing its extension to .php will suffice to "convert" it to a PHP file. If the PHP interpreter doesn't find any php tags in the file, it just won't do anything. Why do those converters exist? Who knows... maybe someone was bored.

Comment: heheh thank you. I change the extension to php and it works. sorry for my noob questions. Now the javascript is not working though. why?

Comment: there's a lot of pointless garbage on the internet, html to php converters are just one example ;)

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need to make everything in `echo`? You can just simply put in normal `html` tag. And put `<?php  ?>` wherever you need PHP code.

Regarding your JS, you are calling `<script type='text/javascript'></script>` twice.